# How to install MySQL on Ubuntu with a particular IP address on a particular port?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ip-address, port

How do I install MySQL on ubuntu 14.04 with the bind address as a particular IP address on port 1723?

Comment: I thinks it is one question how to install a package like MySQL. My guess is that you have done that or can do so. Maybe you want to ask: How do I configure MySQL to listen on a particular port? (NB: Security by obscurity does not work, please google this.)

Comment: @Ned64 The main problem of the question is that it takes 10 seconds to get the answer from a search engine.

Comment: @HaukeLaging That's right. And sad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This configuration typically happens in `my.cnf`, which is usually is `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

```
   [mysqld]
   bind-address = 127.0.0.1
   port = 3306
```

Edit the configuration file specifying your values and restart the MySQL server.